# SQL Group by not returning accurate answer

Tags: sql

[image] it is current result

```
    select cat.sms_schoolcategoryid as categoryId, 
           cat.sms_name as category , 
           count(sch.sms_name) as schoolname, 
           count(stu.accountnumber)NoofStudent
      from Filteredsms_schoolcategory cat 
inner join Filteredsms_school sch
        on cat.sms_schoolcategoryid=sch.sms_schoolcategoryid
inner join FilteredAccount stu
        on sch.sms_schoolid=stu.sms_schoolid
  group by cat.sms_schoolcategoryid, 
           cat.sms_name 
         ;
```

I have three tables one is Category and 2nd is Schools and 3rd is students. i just want to count the schools on behalf of category when I join tables category and school it returns me accurate result and when i join students table with schools table it returns me wrong result. Please Guide me how it is possible.

Comment: Please create a small example, including input, desired output and actual output.

Comment: Can you show us the original data and the result you're gettin back from your query?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the current result and the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: Short answer: use `count(distinct sch.sms_name)`. Long answer: you need to understand SQL better.

Answer (score 0):

There is guesswork involved unless you provide more information on you data model. However, it appears that your issue is rooted in the following:

When you join the student table, for each combination of school category and school (*) you generate  additional records. I.e., your sql no longer counts schools by school category but students.

For a concrete solution and a good advice see @Nick.McDermaid's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 select count(stu.accountnumber) as NoofStudent
       , catsch.categoryId
       , catsch.category
       , catsch.schoolname
 from FilteredAccount stu
 inner join (
     select cat.sms_schoolcategoryid as categoryId
        , cat.sms_name as category 
        , count(sch.sms_name) as schoolname
        , sch.sms_schoolid 
     from Filteredsms_schoolcategory cat 
       inner join Filteredsms_school sch
        on cat.sms_schoolcategoryid = sch.sms_schoolcategoryid
     group by cat.sms_schoolcategoryid, cat.sms_name, sch.sms_schoolid) catsch

  on catsch.sms_schoolid = stu.sms_schoolid

 group catsch.categoryId
       , catsch.category
       , catsch.schoolname
```

Answer (score 0):

`count()` returns the number of non-`NULL` values.  So, your two `count()` will return the same values.  You can quickly fix the query using `count(distinct)`:

```
select cat.sms_schoolcategoryid as categoryId, 
       cat.sms_name as category , 
       count(distinct sch.sms_name) as schoolname, 
       count(distinct stu.accountnumber) as NoofStudent
from Filteredsms_schoolcategory cat inner join
     Filteredsms_school sch
     on cat.sms_schoolcategoryid = sch.sms_schoolcategoryid inner join
     FilteredAccount stu
     on sch.sms_schoolid = stu.sms_schoolid
group by cat.sms_schoolcategoryid, cat.sms_name ;
```

Actually, you probably don't need the second count distinct.  Just `count(stu.accountnumber)` should count the students.